# How do I successfully network computers together using Windows HomeGroup?

Tags: windows, networking, printer, homegroup

I am trying to network a normal USB printer so that all computers on my network can print from it, but no computer on my network can see my HomeGroup...

I have a router connected to a switch, which then has Ethernet connections to 4 Windows 8.1 PC's and 4 Windows 10 PC's.

All PC's have the same default "WORKGROUP" name and are on a Private Network.

One of the Windows 8.1 PC's has a printer installed on it, and when I created a HomeGroup on this one, none of the other PC's can see it.

Ping-ing any of the PC's works, so the computers can see each other.

I then noticed that the Ethernet network name on my PC is "Network 4", while others are "Network 3", "Network 2" or "Network 6".

So I created a HomeGroup on a PC with "Network 2" and tried to join on another computer with same network name. Still didnt work.

Can't find any decent help online.
Can anyone provide some information on what might be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Best typo of the week - Windows HopeGroup….

Comment: I've no idea what you problem is, but I can tell you it's nothing to do with the name of the network connection ... if you right click on a network connection you will see you can rename it to anything you like ...

Comment: You created the homegroup on one computer, then entered the "password" for that homegroup on the other computers so that they would join the home group?  In the case of homegroups the workgroup has nothing to do with it.  The "password" is an alphanumeric string that is assigned when you create the homegroup on the first computer.

Comment: Yes, I know I have to enter the password on each computer, but each computer says no homegroup found on network, click to create one.